# Graphing web url hits via loki logs in grafana: how to get count_over_time to return 0 instead of null for an empty time period?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I am trying to graph the hits on a particular url over time using loki log data in grafana. I have the following LogQL query:

```
sum(
  count_over_time(
    {job="nginx-access", hostname="myhost", filename="/var/log/nginx/myhost_access.log"}
    | json
    | request = "/news"
    [1m]
  ) 
)
```

But the `count_over_time` call counts empty ranges as `null` not `0`. This then causes issues when graphing this. The size of an empty set is 0, not null. This seems very odd. You can see this here:

[image: null values instead of zero from count_over_time]

How can i replace all the null results with 0?
Is there another metric aggregation function that I should use?

Comment: Isn't the settings `null as zero` under `Stacking and null value` enough in a panel visualization?

Comment: Did any one found answer for this